# Why would a Lucene search using a ComplexPhraseQueryParser throw an exception for some content, but not all content?

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene 8.2, but have also verified this on 8.9.

My query string is either ""by~1 word~1"", or ""ky~1 word~1"".

I am looking for a phrase of these 2 words, with potential 1 character mispelling, or fuzziness.

I realize that 'by' is usually a stop word, that is why I also tested with 'ky'.

My simplified test content is either "AC-2.b word", "AC-2.k word", "AC-2.y word".

The first part of the test content is pulled from actual data my customers are trying to search.

For the query with 'by~1' the exception occurs if the content has '.b' or .y', but not '.k'

For the query with 'ky~1' the exception occurs if the content has '.k' or .y', but not '.b'

Here is the test code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.*;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.*;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.*;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.*;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexOptions;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.complexPhrase.ComplexPhraseQueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;

public class phraseTest {

    public static Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    public static IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(
            analyzer);
    public static RAMDirectory ramDirectory = new RAMDirectory();
    public static IndexWriter indexWriter;
    public static Query queryToSearch = null;
    public static IndexReader idxReader;
    public static IndexSearcher idxSearcher;
    public static TopDocs hits;
    public static String query_field = "Content";

    // Pick only one content string
    // public static String content = "AC-2.b word";
    public static String content = "AC-2.k word";
    // public static String content = "AC-2.y word";

    // Pick only one query string
    // public static String queryString = "\"by~1 word~1\"";
    public static String queryString = "\"ky~1 word~1\"";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Content           is\n  " + content);
        System.out.println("Query field       is " + query_field);
        System.out.println("Query String      is '" + queryString + "'");

        Document doc = new Document(); // create a new document

        /**
         * Create a field with term vector enabled
         */
        FieldType type = new FieldType();
        type.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
        type.setStored(true);
        type.setStoreTermVectors(true);
        type.setTokenized(true);
        type.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);

        //term vector enabled
        Field cField = new Field(query_field, content, type);
        doc.add(cField);

        try {
            indexWriter = new IndexWriter(ramDirectory, config);
            indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
            indexWriter.close();

            idxReader = DirectoryReader.open(ramDirectory);
            idxSearcher = new IndexSearcher(idxReader);
            ComplexPhraseQueryParser qp =
                new ComplexPhraseQueryParser(query_field, analyzer);
            queryToSearch = qp.parse(queryString);

            // Here is where the searching, etc starts
            hits = idxSearcher.search(queryToSearch, idxReader.maxDoc());
            System.out.println("scoreDoc size: " + hits.scoreDocs.length);

            // highlight the hits ...

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the exception (using Lucene 8.2):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown query type "org.apache.lucene.search.ConstantScoreQuery" found in phrase query string "ky~1 word~1"
    at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.complexPhrase.ComplexPhraseQueryParser$ComplexPhraseQuery.rewrite(ComplexPhraseQueryParser.java:325)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.rewrite(IndexSearcher.java:666)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:439)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:564)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.searchAfter(IndexSearcher.java:416)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:427)
    at phraseTest.main(phraseTest.java:79)`
```

Am I using ComplexPhraseQueryParser wrong?

Is this a bug in Lucene?

Comment: Just an observation: You are attempting to use the `~` (fuzzy search) operator inside a _phrase_ term (that is, a sequence of words inside double quotes). But as the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_9_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Fuzzy_Searches) states: "_To do a fuzzy search use the tilde, "~", symbol at the end of a Single word Term_". A single word term is not surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: It looks to me that you are attempting to build a query more like this:  `ky~1 AND word~1` - but not exactly that, because you also care about the terms being adjacent, and in a particular order. Therefore [two-word shingles](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_9_0/analyzers-common/index.html) may be what you need to generate, when indexing this data.

Comment: @andrewjames In looking at the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_9_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html) I see an example of the form "(john jon jonathan~) Peters*" which seems to indicate Fuzzy modifiers on phrase terms is allowed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't control the number of terms in the phrase queries. The above is an example I shrunk down to 2, but it originated from a 5 term phrase query. So I don't think shingles would work for us. But, thanks for that link. I learned something new today (TIL).

Comment: My apologies - your question was very clear. My reading of your question was completely incorrect.

Comment: No worries. Your second comment nailed what I'm trying to do to a tee. I think the problem I'm seeing boils down to a fuzzy query reducing to a single character, and the single character appearing in the list of tokens (but I may be wrong). So maybe a term like 'dog~2' would have trouble with 'd', 'o', 'g' tokens.

Comment: I have confirmed. Using my example with 'dog~2' as the first query term and a content string that ends in '.d' or '.o' or '.g', generates the same exception.

Comment: I can create your error with something as simple as `content = "x"` and `queryString ="\"ab~1 y~1\""`. I can also prevent the error by removing the `~1` from the `y~1`. More generally when I have a single character item in my query, I can prevent the error by not adding `~1` to that single character - or by ensuring there is not a single character in the content(!). So, this appears to be a complex combination of factors and may _potentially_ be a bug - although I am not familiar enough with `ComplexPhraseQueryParser` to be confident about that.